# Problem using GitHub api with Python dict "Problems parsing JSON"

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests, github-api

I am trying to use the GitHub api for creating a new file. As per the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file)

this can be done via a PUT request.

I am using the requests package for making the request. The GitHub api endpoint accepts valid json objects as input, i.e. where strings  are within double quotes.

My data has the following format -

```
{
  'message': 'Updated learn.md',
  'content': 'ZW51bTM0PT0xLjEuNAotZSBnaXQraHR0cHM6Ly9naXRodWIuY29tL29wZW50b2svT3BlbnRvay1QeXRob24tU0RLLmdpdEAwMzU4YTI0ZDM0ZTkzMjVjYzRhODNhYmQxZTVjMGJmYzQ2M2ZkMjYwI2VnZz1vcGVudG9rCnB5dHo9PTIwMTYuNApyZXF1ZXN0cz09Mi4xMC4wCgo=',
  'branch': 'master'
}
```

Since I am putting the data which is in the form of a Python dictionary it is having single quotes, but GitHub isn't accepting it and is giving a 400 response of "Problems parsing JSON" as shown below

```
{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file"
}
```

I have verified that the problem is because of quotes only by using postman to make the PUT request, in that case it was successful.

The correct data is shown below

```
{
  "message": "Updated learn.md",
  "content": "ZW51bTM0PT0xLjEuNAotZSBnaXQraHR0cHM6Ly9naXRodWIuY29tL29wZW50b2svT3BlbnRvay1QeXRob24tU0RLLmdpdEAwMzU4YTI0ZDM0ZTkzMjVjYzRhODNhYmQxZTVjMGJmYzQ2M2ZkMjYwI2VnZz1vcGVudG9rCnB5dHo9PTIwMTYuNApyZXF1ZXN0cz09Mi4xMC4wCgo=",
  "branch": "master"
}
```

Here is how I am making the call

```
def put_data_to_github(self, url, data):
    headers = {}
    headers['Authorization'] = "token " + self.auth_token
    response = requests.put(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    return response
```

How can I make valid JSON objects in Python so that GitHub api accepts it? How Can I achieve this?

Comment: Please can you share the full Traceback error?

Comment: Included the error received in the Github response

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must convert your data to json before sending..

```
import json
...
response = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

Comment: I tried this solution earlier, but my data had a byte string, I decoded it and then used json.dumps, which did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Hm...When using the [`Update File Contents`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents#create-or-update-file-contents) Github API, the `content` key requires a b64 encoded value. I get a `TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable` error when trying to use the above solution.

Comment: @SeaDude see the comment above yours for the solution.

Comment: Yes, I was reading that comment. When the base64 is decoded I can't use it as input for the `content` key. [Here's the write-up.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73863293/python-github-rest-api-problems-with-the-update-file-contents-request)

Comment: Now I see what @Shahrukh-Mohammad was doing. I don't know why, but his suggestion coupled with changing the `data` parameter to `json` in the `request.put()` worked for me. See write up above.